# L'Hospital's rule: using many times okay?

Tags: calculus, limits

This was a question in a practice exam for the national Finnish math exam for high schoolers. We were given the swedish wikipedia page for L'Hospital's rule (not part of the curriculum so we had never seen it before) and told to use it to evaluate this:

$$\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{e^x-3x-1}{3x^5}=-\infty$$

Some of us simply derivated the top and bottom functions and inserted 0 and got -2/0 which would be -infinity, right?

Now because the wikipedia article talked about using the rule multiple times some derivated top and bottom 5 times, so that we get e^x/360. Then insertion gives 1/360. Because of the rules regarding national tests we haven't been given any answers yet, and we would really like to know!

Thanks in advance, and hope this isn't the wrong place to post something like this!

Comment: You can only use L'Hopital's rule multiple times if evaluating the limit continues to be indeterminate at each intermediate point.  As $-2/0$ is not indeterminate, you were correct to stop.

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! L'Hospital's rule is valid as long as you have an indeterminate form. After the first step, it is no more indeterminate. Anyway, it is best to avoid using it: as you can see it is a dangerous rule, as one often forgets to check its hypotheses of validity, and, when it works, using Taylor's formula works as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should research the rule. It is only applicable under certain conditions. One of these conditions is that it can only be used when the limit to be found is of either of the indeterminate forms $\frac 00$ or $\frac{\pm\infty} {\pm\infty} $.

The initial limit is of the first form so the rule is applicable. But after differentiating top and bottom, the result is of the form $\frac{-2} 0$, so the rule no longer applies. Regardless, you can immediately evaluate that limit as $-\infty$ without needing the rule. But you cannot apply the rule any further (so differentiating again is wrong).

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^x-3x-1}{3x^5}\end{align}$$

The numerator and denominator are tending to zero. You study the limit of the quotients of the derivatives $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^x-3}{15x^4}$$

Now, in this one, the numerator is tending to $1-3=-2$, while the denominator is tending to $0^+$. Therefore, the limit of the quotient is $-\infty$. L'Hostpital tells you that the original limit is $-\infty$ too.

Looking at the limit of the quotient of further derivatives would give you limits that L'Hospital doesn't relate to the original limit.